# Average every four rows but preserve timestamp values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, mean

What is the fastest way in pandas to average every four rows in a dataframe?

My problem is that I have a program recording data every 15 seconds which looks like this:

```
1477892758, 10
1477892773, 20
1477892788, 30
1477892803, 40
1477892818, 15
1477892833, 25
1477892848, 35
1477892863, 45
```

...etc where the first column is the Unix timestamp and the second is the data (my real data set has many more columns).

I only want to have data for once per minute. How can I average the data for every four rows but still preserve a meaningful timestamp? Ideally the timestamp would be the first in the series, so I would have something like this in the end:

```
1477892758, 25
1477892818, 30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` by `index` floor divided by `4` and [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) for first column `first` and for second `mean`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 30, 3: 40, 4: 15, 5: 25, 6: 35, 7: 45}, 'A': {0: 1477892758, 1: 1477892773, 2: 1477892788, 3: 1477892803, 4: 1477892818, 5: 1477892833, 6: 1477892848, 7: 1477892863}})
print (df)
            A   B
0  1477892758  10
1  1477892773  20
2  1477892788  30
3  1477892803  40
4  1477892818  15
5  1477892833  25
6  1477892848  35
7  1477892863  45
```

```
print (df.index // 4)
Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype='int64')

print (df.groupby(df.index // 4).agg({'A':'first', 'B':'mean'})[['A','B']])
            A   B
0  1477892758  25
1  1477892818  30
```

If first column is `index` use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 20, 30, 40, 15, 25, 35, 45]}, index=[1477892758, 1477892773, 1477892788, 1477892803, 1477892818, 1477892833, 1477892848, 1477892863])
print (df)
             A
1477892758  10
1477892773  20
1477892788  30
1477892803  40
1477892818  15
1477892833  25
1477892848  35
1477892863  45
```

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = list('AB')
print (df)
            A   B
0  1477892758  10
1  1477892773  20
2  1477892788  30
3  1477892803  40
4  1477892818  15
5  1477892833  25
6  1477892848  35
7  1477892863  45


print (df.groupby(df.index // 4).agg({'A':'first', 'B':'mean'})[['A','B']])
            A   B
0  1477892758  25
1  1477892818  30
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to generalize this to a dataframe with an arbitrary number of columns?

Comment: I think you need create custom `dict`, see this perfect [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40697343/2901002).